# How can I do performance testing in Xcode 6.3 with Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, testing, performance-testing

Xcode 6.3 does not show performance annotations for tests with `measureBlock` function. Without annotation how can I set the performance baseline and check the test performance?

Setting baseline from Report Navigator does not work either. It shows the following error:

> Did not find file for test identifier

[image]

Demo app: https://github.com/evgenyneu/performance_tests_broken_code_xcode_swift

### Known Xcode issue

This issue is probably connected with following known issue in Xcode 6.3. From Xcode 6.3 Release Notes:

> Swift tests are not automatically discovered in this release of Xcode. Test annotations in the source editor sidebar will not appear, and the test navigator and the table of tests in the Test action of the scheme sheet will be empty.
>   You can run Swift tests by selecting Product > Test. Once tests have been run, they appear in the test navigator and the scheme sheet. The following limitations apply:
>
> Tests discovered through execution in this manner provide limited interaction in the test navigator. For example, Run buttons do not appear and clicking on a test in the navigator does not jump to the source code except in the case of a test error.
>   Run buttons and test success/fail indicators will not appear in the source editor.
>   (20373533)

Comment: how did you set baseline then for this?

Comment: @anishparajuli I have set the baseline by clicking the button #3 shown in the screen short.

Comment: i tried the same..but didnot work in xcode 6.3?

Comment: Its fixed with XCode version above 6.3.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534903/performance-testing-in-swift-using-tdd?rq=1